# Can't reach Load Balancer from GCP VM

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

In GCP We are setting up kubernetes 1.14. HA as Stacked etcd topology.

We have created a image where kubernetes binaries are installed.

We have terrafrom script where an instance group is created with 3 master and 5 worker nodes instances using the above image.

Also, in the terrafrom script, we have created a TCP Load Balancing with 6443 port enabled.

I am able to bootstrap one master by running kubeadm init --config=. However, joining the 2nd master fails with below error.

kubeadm join XX.XX.XX.XX:6443 --token 9a08jv.c0izixklcxtmnze7 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:73390a94962247546282a0954cb46f2a282b00534c06aff93773f3fc50aee562 --experimental-control-plane -v 8

`I0423 09:50:33.623004 21078 checks.go:382] validating the presence of executable touch
I0423 09:50:33.623063 21078 checks.go:524] running all checks
I0423 09:50:33.656532 21078 checks.go:412] checking whether the given node name is reachable using net.LookupHost
I0423 09:50:33.656705 21078 checks.go:622] validating kubelet version
I0423 09:50:33.716178 21078 checks.go:131] validating if the service is enabled and active
I0423 09:50:33.723119 21078 checks.go:209] validating availability of port 10250
I0423 09:50:33.723377 21078 checks.go:439] validating if the connectivity type is via proxy or direct
I0423 09:50:33.723445 21078 join.go:441] [preflight] Fetching init configuration
I0423 09:50:33.723486 21078 join.go:474] [preflight] Retrieving KubeConfig objects
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster…
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with ‘kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml’
I0423 09:50:33.725538 21078 round_trippers.go:416] GET https://XX.XX.XX.XX:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config
I0423 09:50:33.725564 21078 round_trippers.go:423] Request Headers:
I0423 09:50:33.725570 21078 round_trippers.go:426] Accept: application/json, /
I0423 09:50:33.725594 21078 round_trippers.go:426] User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.14.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/641856d
I0423 09:50:33.725886 21078 round_trippers.go:441] Response Status: in 0 milliseconds
I0423 09:50:33.725903 21078 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap: failed to get config map: Get https://XX.XX.XX.XX:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config: dial tcp XX.XX.XX.XX:6443: connect: connection refused

Comment: It seems like you are running a self managed Kubernetes cluster in GCE as your issue related to GCE cluster using kubeadm (not GKE). The error message may indicate a network connection issue up to the VM, and I suspect possibly a misconfigured firewall rule.

Comment: is this master already registered as a backend for the load balancer? because of how TCP LB work in GCP, if the VM is a registered backend for the LB all traffic from the VM destined to the LB will be treated as local traffic and stay within the same VM